# Possible Drawbacks of Compiling with /unsafe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, unsafe

I have to compile my assembly with /unsafe in order to use a pointer. I wonder differences when I compile with /unsafe. Please assume that there is no programming faults such as invalid use of pointers etc. Do I lose some performance if I use unsafe compiled assembly? Any memory drawbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using "unsafe" code you basically improve performance, with diect access to a memory and pointer ariphmetics . The usual case of using this is inside .NET code focused on high performance, like for example `3D` rendering kernel engine. Writing stuff like this in `100%` `.NET` code would make application too slow, so pointers come to rescue, especially when we need to deal with "bridges" between `C/C++` libriaries like `OpenGL` (say)

Long story short: you will benefit from it definitely, if you write a good not managed code.

Comment: I wouldn't take this to mean though that your average asp.net site or web forms application would benefit however.  Decisions like this should be made only after proper code profiling has been done.

Comment: @asawyer:  moving to unsafe code is not something that you do to improve a performance in general. You do it when you have several costrains: access som C/C++ library, for example. Dealing with such stuff **within** unsafe code and **out** of it, makes a difference. I don't advertise of using unsafe code everywhere, but considering that you choose it, you have a good reasons of doing that.

Comment: Absolutely, I was just a little concerned someone might read your answer (which is perfectly correct) incorrectly as saying to go ahead and use it for any app for nebulous "performance gains" reasons.

Comment: @asawyer: if you are really concern about performance and you feel *really* good in unmanaged code, just code in C/C++. Good written C/C++ code is unbitten.

Answer (score 1):

Unsafe code may increase an application's performance by removing array bounds checks.

Using unsafe code introduces security and stability risks.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx